# TFS Configuation Error

Tags: tfs, tfsbuild

I'm following a blog post on how to get build services configured on a different domain than the TFS server

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adamroot/archive/2010/03/02/configuring-team-foundation-server-2010-build-services-outside-of-domains-and-domain-trust.aspx

error is

```
Info   @14:25:19.225] +-+-+-+-+-| EventSources.Create |+-+-+-+-+-
[Info   @14:25:19.225] TF255075: The following event source already exists: TFS    Services.
[Info   @14:25:19.225] TF255075: The following event source already exists: TFS  Version Control.
[Info   @14:25:19.225] TF255075: The following event source already exists: TFS WorkItem Tracking.
[Info   @14:25:19.225] TF255075: The following event source already exists: TFS Warehouse.
[Info   @14:25:19.225] TF255075: The following event source already exists: TFS Build.
[Info   @14:25:19.225] TF255075: The following event source already exists: Team Build Service.
[Info   @14:25:19.225] TF255075: The following event source already exists: TFS Proxy Server.
[Info   @14:25:19.225] TF255075: The following event source already exists: TFS Scheduler.
[Info   @14:25:19.225] TF255075: The following event source already exists: TFS Test Management.
[Info   @14:25:19.225] TF255075: The following event source already exists: VSTF Coverage Analysis.
[Info   @14:25:19.225] TF255075: The following event source already exists: TFS Lab Management.
[Info   @14:25:19.225] TF255075: The following event source already exists: TFS Test Rig.
[Info   @14:25:19.225] TF255075: The following event source already exists: TFS Deployment Rig.
[Info   @14:25:19.225] TF255075: The following event source already exists: Team Foundation Error Reporting.
[Info   @14:25:19.225] TF255075: The following event source already exists: VSTF Test Tools Adapter.
[Info   @14:25:19.225] TF255075: The following event source already exists: Team Web Access.
[Error  @14:25:19.459] TF255070: Configuring services for Team Foundation Build failed with the following exception: Some or all identity references could not be translated..
[Error  @14:25:19.475] 
Exception Message: Some or all identity references could not be translated. (type IdentityNotMappedException)

Exception Stack Trace:    at   System.Security.Principal.NTAccount.Translate(IdentityReferenceCollection sourceAccounts,  Type targetType, Boolean forceSuccess)
at System.Security.Principal.NTAccount.Translate(Type targetType)
at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Common.UserNameUtil.GetSecurityIdentifier(String userName)
at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Common.UserNameUtil.IsWellKnownAccount(String userName, WellKnownSidType wellKnownType)
at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Config.BuildServiceHostUtilities.TranslateAccount(String accountName, String domain)
at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Config.BuildServiceHostUtilities.GetServerUserName(IBuildServiceHost serviceHost, String serviceUser)
at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Config.BuildServiceHostUtilities.Register(IBuildServiceHost serviceHost, String userName, String password, X509Certificate2 serverCertificate)
at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Admin.TeamBuildInstaller.RegisterWithApplicationServer(TeamBuild tb, OperationContext context)
at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Admin.TeamBuildInstaller.Apply(OperationContext context, StateReporter reporter)

[Error  @14:25:19.475] TF255184: An error occurred during operation. Message=TF255070: Configuring services for Team Foundation Build failed with the following exception: Some or all identity references could not be translated...
[Error  @14:25:19.475] TF255248: The process applying the configuration must be terminated due to an error.
[Error  @14:25:19.475] TF255247: An error occurred while applying the following configuration: Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Admin.ConfigurationApplyException: TF255070: Configuring services for Team Foundation Build failed with the following exception: Some or all identity references could not be translated..
at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Admin.ErrorList.HandleError(IResult result)
at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Admin.ErrorList.Add(IResult result)
at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Admin.TeamBuildInstaller.Apply(OperationContext context, StateReporter reporter)
at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Admin.TeamBuild.Apply(OperationContext context)
at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Admin.ConfigurationNode.ApplyIfReady(OperationContext context)
at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Admin.LogicalTier.Apply(OperationalMode mode).
```